# call table name via property file in java

Tags: java, mysql

i am trying to call table name via property file in java

### java program

```
String table1 =confgProperties.getProperty(ApplicationProperties.APP_DB_TABLE1);

String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM" +table1;
```

When am trying to run above lines in java program an getting below error

```
java.lang.Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=.;ount(*) FROMuser;FROM, DRIVER=3.65.97

Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=.;ount(*) FROMuser;FROM, DRIVER=3.65.97
```

---

property file

```
table1=user.IC12;
```

Please provide some suggestions

Comment: you should give a space after FROM..   `"SELECT count(*) FROM " + table1`

Comment: See also: [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/) for why you should not build SQL this way.

Comment: I tried giving space at first attempt after FROM but it's not working

Comment: @mjn : do u have any other suggestions so that I can call table name from property file

Comment: What error do you get after adding space after `FROM`?